# how do I remove a large file entry from one gerrithub repository and then get autoreplication to github restarted

Tags: git, github, gerrit, rebase

There is a lot of questions similar to this issue, however I could not find one which would solve my issue

issue is this:
some time ago I checked in a large file in my gerrithub project, and later made a checkin where I removed it, somehow this large file stopped the automatic replication to Github, and at a later stage I noticed this - I wanted then to remove the large file and make a merge for github with my latest changes, however the large file kept popping up when git tried to merge

```
-o-o-o-o-o-x-o-o-o-o master
     |
     o-o-o-o mybranch (origin where issue large file was added)
         | 
         o = (where file was removed)
```

I ended up with making a checkout from Github, then copy from my gerrithub and then checkin -- this is NOT what I wanted, since this destroys history and is a big NO-NO if more than one person is working on the branch.

First I tried to do following:

```
git pull <url to gerrit> <branch>
git rebase
```

This however would stop at the issue file even after doing following:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <issuefilename>' <commit id>..HEAD
```

Is there a way to get Github to ignore large files and just continue with checkin??  or is there a safe way to remove this commit ???

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no solution besides rewriting history (and you say that this is not what you want). That's why you only find solutions related to `git filter-branch`.

Depending on with whom you are working with, rewriting history might be possible with some communication amongst the team. Generally, it's a bad practice, but if it's needed, find some way to get around that step by sending out to your peers that such change will happen and how to deal with it.

Comment: Yes so far I have walked around it by cherry pick and then ignore history when checkin, however doing this will NOT restore the automatic replication between GerritHub and GitHub - I fear that there is no solution but creating a new branch in GitHub and a new i GerritHub based on this new branch - basically start from scratch and loosing all history - I really do not want to do this, not just yet - so I am currently manually updating GitHub with my changes from GerritHub - I am hoping that some solution will pop up with time - perhaps if I could tell GH to just ignore large files and continue

Comment: Just remove the repo on Github and re-create it. Replication will push the state contained in the Gerrit server. Alternatively, I think you can just delete the branch(es) that contained the large file. The next time, Gerrithub's replication should push everything.

Comment: Actually I think I found a better approach - first use git stash - second use git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <filename>' -f HEAD  - third use git stash apply - and final use git push origin <your branch>

Comment: how ever the autoreply is still not working between GerritHub and Github

Comment: That's what I was saying. It doesn't matter, how you rewrite history. Replication to Github will not work, if a [fast-forward](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge.html) is not possible (as AFAIK Gerrithub does not do forced pushes). Re-create the repo on Github and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, and with history intact -- I did following on both GitHub and GerritHub repositories

1. `git stash`

   *(only on GitHub)* `git remote add upstream <gerrit project url>`

   `git pull upstream <branch>`
2. `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <filename>' -f HEAD`
3. `git stash apply`
4. `git push origin <your branch>`

it took a long time with GerritHub and it was out of service for the duration, however it came back and history was intact and I could see that the large file was replaced in the log with " --- /dev/null "

After this I tried making a normal `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/<branch>` with GerritHub, and it was then replicated to GitHub